# Accessing the current row's index value for a calculation in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a datetime index. I'm attempting to add a new column that will contain that row's date time index value and subtract 1 workday.

I'm using a function in the workday library which simply takes a `datetime`, an integer and subtracts that many workdays from the starting `datetime`.

The problem I'm having is when I try to apply that function to a `data.index.values` it is an `array` of the index values.

How can I access just that current row's date? Do I have to do an apply or lamda to loop through every row?

[image]

```
                           CLES12Z     RBE  ...  CLEDelta  PeriodDiff
Timestamp                                   ...                      
2019-07-31 10:20:00+00:00     3.22  1.8574  ...      0.03       -0.01
2019-07-31 10:21:00+00:00     3.22  1.8574  ...      0.00        0.00
2019-07-31 10:22:00+00:00     3.23  1.8593  ...      0.06       -0.05
2019-07-31 10:23:00+00:00     3.24  1.8580  ...      0.04       -0.03
2019-07-31 10:24:00+00:00     3.24  1.8559  ...     -0.07        0.01
```

And here is what I've tried:

```
import workdays

data = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='Timestamp', parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
data['running_day'] = workdays.workday(data.index.values, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **timedelta** object from  library **datetime**. Timedelta object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times.

> from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta
>
> Original_date=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0])
>
> df["Updated_Date"]=Original_date + timedelta(days =-1)
>
> df

Comment: the key thing is I need to subtract 1 workday. not just 1 regular day. That's why im making use of the Workdays library - however, that just needs a singular datetime, not a list or series hence why I'm trying to access each row's index value